# Density Forecasts with GAMLSS

Tags: forecasting, density-function, gamlss

Does someone know the function to create density forecasts within the GAMLSS Package?

The predict. Formula is not the right one. Predict do Point Forecasts

Answer (score 4):

GAMLSS uses distributional assumptions, and estimates and forecasts conditional distribution parameters. So you would need to use the `what` parameter to `predict.gamlss` to tell it which distribution parameters to predict, e.g., `mu`, `sigma`, `nu` or `tau`. (Actually, you will probably want to use `type=response`, because the default `type=link` gives you the logit prediction.) Then feed these parameters into the distribution you used originally in fitting the GAMLSS model, and use the appropriate density function.

Comment: Thank you for answer.

How do I feed the parameters into the distribution?
And how do I find the appropriate density function?

Comment: That will depend on what you fitted in the first place per `gamlss.famliy`. If you could edit your question to include a [Minimum Working Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/452096) (use `dput()`!) and notify me here in another comment, I will try to take a look.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but I found the right function. Its the prodist() Function